# An Error Was Encountered The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled in ubuntu codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, ubuntu

Installed mongodb extension using pecl

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

and

updated the php.ini file by adding `extension=mongodb.so`

but still getting the error 
`The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled`

Using php version 7
and codeigniter 3.1.8.....
please help me..

Comment: Did you restarted your server

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?